# onSelect event on dynamically created layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm creating different layers dynamically full of features, everything on-the-fly, and I need to do some stuff when each specific feature is selected. I can't paste the actual source code here as it has dependencies and it's quite long also, but you can imagine something like the following:

```
if (e.Bubbles) {
     jQuery.each(e.Bubbles, function (i, obj) {
         jQuery.each(obj, function (n, el) {

             /* features and layers ... */
             var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(el[1],el[0]);

             /* some code here ... */
         });

         layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(i, {styleMap: e.Style});
         map.addLayer(layer);
         e.Layers.push(layer);

         /* etc. */
```

When I'm trying to bind the `onSelect` event to the layer, it works but it replaces the previous layer behavior, so the last layer in the `loop` works fine when you clicking on the features, but only the last layer. Here is my code (inside the loop):

```
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    Layer,
    {
        clickout: false, 
        toggle: false,
        multiple: false, 
        hover: false,
     }
 );

selectControl.activate();

layer.events.on({
    "featureselected": function(event) {
        console.log(event.feature);
    }
});
```

So, the `selectControl` will be replaced inside the loop each time and it will lose its own functionality for the previous ones, and just works for the latest layer.

I tried pass all the layers as an array as well (which is supposed to work) but without any success.

```
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    e.Layers,
    {
        clickout: false, 
        toggle: false,
        multiple: false, 
        hover: false,
        onSelect: function(event) {
            console.log(event.feature);
        },
    }
);

selectControl.activate();
```

Answer (score 1):

So, here is the answer!

```
if (typeof selectControl == "object") {
    selectControl.setLayer(map.getLayersByClass("OpenLayers.Layer.Vector"));

} else {

    selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
        layer,
        {
            clickout: false, 
            toggle: false,
            multiple: false, 
            hover: false,
        }
    );

    map.addControl(selectControl);
    selectControl.activate();               
}

layer.events.on({
    "featureselected": function(event) {
        console.log(event.feature);
    }
});
```